# Keep an absolute positioned HTML element in it's position

Tags: html, css

[image]

The span tag `red arrow` which has `position: absolute` is at the bottom right corner as intended. When I start typing text into the `content` container arrow starts floating away.

Setting `content` height to `auto` or `100%` did not fix the issue.

How can we keep span tag `red arrow` fixed on the right bottom corner irrespective of height of the `content` element?

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-shockley-dcp59?file=/src/App.js

HTML

```
<div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="content">
          <div suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable="true">
            Test
          </div>
        </div>
        <span className="helper"></span>
      </div>

      <div className="container">
        <div className="content">
          <div suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable="true">
            <p>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
              industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
              ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
              type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
              survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
              electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
              popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
              containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
              publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
              Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span className="helper"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

style.css

```
.container {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.helper::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-right: 4px solid red;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Ever considered position:fixed?

Comment: Yes @Nikita - Same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I'd move the scrolling behaviour definition to `.content` and assign `position: relative;` to the `.container`.

```css
.container {
  position: relative; /* new */
  overflow: hidden; /* changed */
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  width: inherit; /* new */
  height: inherit; /* new */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* new */
  overflow-y: scroll; /* new */
}

.helper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-right: 4px solid red;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable="true">
        Test
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="helper"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable="true">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
        publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="helper"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Note: I've changed `className` to `class` to make the code snippet work. I didn't make any changes to the HTML structure.*

Answer (score 0):

Your helper div is in the wrong place. It needs to be inside the `.content` div and the `.content` div needs to have `position: relative`. Right now the helper is relative to the parent container, not the content. Also you don't need to use a psuedo element for your helper shape, those styles can be applied directly to the element and `content: ""` removed.

**HTML**

```
 <div className="App">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="content">
      <div suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable="true">
        Test
      </div>
      <span className="helper"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="container">
    <div className="content">
      <div suppressContentEditableWarning={true} contentEditable="true">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
          industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
          ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
          type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
          survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
          electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
          popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets
          containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
          publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
          Lorem Ipsum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <span className="helper"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

styles.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  transform: translate(0px, 10px);
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.content {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
}
.helper {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3px;
  bottom: 3px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-right: 4px solid red;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
```

Comment: I made the changes as per your suggestion. It actually changes the design. When loaded, helper is not at the bottom right corner for the first container and when text is added it disappears. Intended behavior is to keep it visible all the time at right bottom corner.

https://codesandbox.io/s/red-glitter-8w5vq?file=/src/styles.css